# How to import antd4 icons when necessary?

Tags: icons, antd

The docs:

```
import { MessageOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

<MessageOutlined />;
```

However, the fact is :
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwo86.png)

I tried to use this way:

```
import FileSearchOutlined from '@ant-design/icons/FileSearchOutlined';
```

but failed.

Does anyone know how to resolve this ?

Comment: this code is working fine, can you explain your error, or provide a working fiddle?

Comment: also, there is no difference b/w both kind of import strategies, if you want to just import the icon you want to use, your code is fine

Answer (score 0):

I tried several different ways of creating custom icons, and the one that was easiest and worked best was to use this method.

```
import { iconName } from '@ant-design/icons';

<div icon={<iconName/>} />
```

Comment: I've attempted to fix the formatting so it looks as you intended. Did I get it right? If not, you should be able to [edit] to get it where you need it.